# How to use # sign as an anchor while url rewriting with .htaccess on apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, anchor

i have .htaccess that works fine with shorty rewriting rules like

```
RewriteRule   ^blog/(.+)$   blog_post.php?blogSEOBaslik=$1   [L]
```

But there is a page `about.php` which includes subnavigation via `<li><a href="#resume">` named anchor. When i apply a rule like:

```
RewriteRule   ^about/(.+)$   about.php\#$1  [L]
```

not behave as usual, standart `about.php#resume` anchor do.
How do i use named anchors in url rewriting rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NE` flag for `not encoding` the resulting URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /BAH/

RewriteRule ^about/(.+)$ about.php#$1 [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: It gives
Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22

Comment: Last situation: RewriteRule   ^about/(.+)$   about.php#$1  [NE,L,R]

Comment: With just this rule in my .htaccess when I enter `/about/abc` it got redirected to `/about.php#abc`.

Comment: Ok, let me restart apache, and retry this.

Comment: it still gives the error 403 and try to look at `http://localhost/C:/xampp/xampp_2/htdocs/BAH/about.php#contact`

Comment: There is no change, Error 403 :/

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess OR any other .htaccess in your system? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: And now simplyfy it to: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^about/(.+)$   about.php#$1  [NC,L,R]`

Comment: Not `NC` it should be `NE`. What is filesystem location of this `.htaccess`?

Comment: I tried NE either. The .htaccess stays near index.php in the main folder. Physical address: C:/xampp/xampp_2/htdocs/BAH/

Comment: Ah that's why I was asking again & again. And `about/` is sub directory in `/BAH/` also?

Comment: No :/ all necessary files in same BAH folder. Also the .htaccess file.

Comment: Huh! it works like a charm. But what if i add other rules below this one? I thank you very much.

Comment: Sure you can add other rules below this.